# Find three ages

Tags: puzzle

> Transposing the two digits of A's age gives B's age. The difference
>   between their ages is twice C's age and В is ten times as old as С.
>   What are the three ages?

Let A's age be $ab=10a+b$ so B's age is $ba=10b+a$

$$10b+a=10 \times( \text{C's age}),  \frac{10b+a}{5}=2 \times (\text{ C's age})$$

$$|10(a-b)+(b-a)|=\frac{10b+a}{5}$$

If $a>b$ then $10(a-b)+(a-b)=\frac{10b+a}{5}$ gives $54a-65b=0$

If $b>a$ then $10(b-a)+(b-a)=\frac{10b+a}{5}$ gives $45b-56a=0$

None of the last two equations give $a$ and $b$ as single digit.

Comment: Write $|10(a-b)+(b-a)| = |9(a-b)|$ and try those last two lines again.

Comment: A = 54, B= 45, C =4.5

Comment: You made a sign error. If $A\gt B$ then the difference in their ages is given by:$$(10a+b)-(10b+a)=10(a-b)\color{red}{-}(a-b)=9(a-b)$$